# Scala How to get sublist by index

Tags: scala

I have a List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5) and trying to get a sublist: List(3, 4) from it by the following way:

```
List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5).slice(this.size - 3 , this.size - 1 )
```

But I got an error

```
error: value size is not a member of object
```

How can I use "this" parameter in Scala just like in Java. Are there other ways to achieve the goal. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you want to use `size`? Doesn't `List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5).slice(2, 4)` suit you? Also to count from the end you can do one-liner `List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5).reverse.slice(1, 3).reverse`

Comment: I think he means that he also wants to get a sublist from an index to an element near the last element, in the case he doesn't know exactly the size of the list so he has to use the "size" function

Comment: As a general note, `List` doesn't have good random access performance. If you are looking for something that can be indexed in to `Vector` is more suitable.

Comment: @Kolmar : i have a dynamic Collection and I want remove some elements ( at end of Collection) but I dont know what size of that collection.
I able do it with some ways as: keep List.size in Val and call that val in next line. But i want find other way better than that same 
List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5).slice(this.size - 3 , this.size - 1 )
Have we any way with scala ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should first declare the list, and then refer to the list using its name `list`, not `this`:

```
val list = List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5)
list.slice(list.size -3, list.size -1)
```

If you really want to do this in one line, then use `reverse`, but it's not very efficient:

```
List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5).reverse.slice(1, 3).reverse
```

By the way, that code wouldn't be valid in Java either. `this` refers to the enclosing object, not to the list.

Comment: yeah. You right but i want find other way and write in one line.
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @VietSon yes, using `reverse`. I've updated my answer

Comment: @VietSon, you can't. You need an object to call `size` on, and the only way to get one is to store this object somewhere first. You can do a workaround with something like shapeless kestrel combinator: `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) |> { list => list.slice(list.size-3, list.size-1) }` however this is not that different from creating a separate val. I suggest to keep it simple and go with this answer in its original form.

Answer (score 5):

If you want last 3 or n elements, you can use `takeRight(3)` or `takeRight(n)`.

Edit based on the question edit:

If you need to not take first `f` and last `l` elements then

```
List(1,2,3,....n).drop(f).dropRight(l)
```

For your case it will be `List(1,2,3,4,5).drop(2).dropRight(1)`

Comment: No, I also want to get some elements in the middle, not only left or right side

Comment: List(1,2,3,4,5).drop(2).dropRight(1)) is ok but I want to do it in general by using "size" function in Scala

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the word this is not pointing your List, if you want to take some parameter in the middle of the List use take and takeRigth please read the Scala Docs at the end is a link

```
val my_lst = List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5)
my_lst.takeRight(3).take(2)

my_lst: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 4)
```

first takeRight with the index counting on right my_lst.size - thepositions, so you must write thepositions and then how many elements you want in your new subList

Here is a explanations of how work the methods in scala List

from Scala Help Doc

> def slice(from: Int, until: Int): List[A]
>
> returns
>
> ```
> a list containing the elements greater than or equal to index from extending up to (but not including) index until of this list.
> ```
>
> Definition Classes
>       List → LinearSeqOptimized → IterableLike → TraversableLike → GenTraversableLike Example:

// Given a list
val letters = List('a','b','c','d','e')

// `slice` returns all elements beginning at index `from` and afterwards,
// up until index `until` (excluding index `until`.)
letters.slice(1,3) // Returns List('b','c')

in you case use length or size

```
scala> val my_lst = List(1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5)
my_lst: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> my_lst.slice(my_lst.length-3,my_lst.length)
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```

but really scala List class has a lot of functions that can fit you. In your case if you want the last 3 elemments use takeRight

> def takeRight(n: Int): List[A]
>
> Selects last n elements.
>
> n
>
> ```
> the number of elements to take returns
>
> a list consisting only of the last n elements of this list, or else the whole list, if it has less than n elements.
> ```
>
> Definition Classes
>       List → IterableLike

```
scala> my_lst.takeRight(3)
res2: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)
```

Take a look at the Scala [Docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

Comment: Why I get -1 by this answer?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question. In general I also want to get some elements in the middle, not only left or right side by using the "size" function in Scala

Comment: I make an edit to my answer, I hope that help you ;-) @VietSon

Comment: Is there other way to not have to declare "val my_lst"?

Comment: What is the problem using val? in the question do not point. He only wants to get a sublist so I kept the original without change. Of course you can store the old an new list in the same var or use mutable list

Comment: @Anquegi :Just find other way better than using 'val'.

Answer (score -3):

You have a List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

1) Is that a Function or Object or a Class?

2) You want to use return values from List( x , x , 3 , 4 , x )

3) you need to use size outside of the parentheses to return the value from your new List function...

4) create a function to complete this step then return it to a variable...

5) when you fire the function List() use variables with List( A , B , C , D , E )

6) all objects must be completely declared before use. for example, How can you use a basketball without air inside? or How can you use a football without being covered in pigskin? or How can you use a computer without a CPU? all components of objects must be completely declared and working properly in programming!

7) All data, functions, objects inside your List() function must be working properly or ... functioning . . .

8)  You said "In general I also want to get some elements in the middle" ..

9) As a veteran programmer... You have to know exactly where the elements are in your List() function

10) Also from the start, before all these functions you wish to "use" you must load the classes, that is filled with all the functions you use, at the head of your program.

11) you cannot use a function the same way you use an object or a class!

12) Lastly, you just want to be creative when the programming language sets the rules or boundaries ...Scala is not Java ...

Does this help? with "error: value size is not a member of object"