# Splitting a Scala List into parts using a given list of part sizes.[Partitioning]

Tags: scala, list, collections

I got two lists:

```
val list1:List[Int]   =  List(5, 2, 6)

val list2:List[Any]  =  List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j","k")
```

such that  `list1.sum >= list2.size`

> I want a list of lists formed with elements in list2 consecutively
>   with the sizes mentioned in list1.

For example:

if list1 is `List(5,2,4)` the result I want is:

```
List(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),List("f", "g"),List("h", "i", "j","k"))
```

if list1 is `List(5,4,6)` the result I want is:

```
List(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),List("f", "g","h", "i"),List("j","k"))
```

How can I do that with concise code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn `list2` into an `Iterator` then map over `list1`.

```
val itr = list2.iterator
list1.map(itr.take(_).toList)
//res0: List[List[Any]] = List(List(a, b, c, d, e), List(f, g), List(h, i, j, k))
```

---

**update**:
While this appears to give the desired results, it has been pointed out elsewhere that reusing the iterator is actually unsafe and its behavior is not guaranteed.

With some modifications a safer version can be achieved.

```
val itr = list2.iterator
list1.map(List.fill(_)(if (itr.hasNext) Some(itr.next) else None).flatten)
```

-- or --

```
import util.Try
val itr = list2.iterator
list1.map(List.fill(_)(Try(itr.next).toOption).flatten)
```

Comment: I would refer to the post by you here for my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415013/why-scala-string-objects-iterator-and-listint-objects-iterator-are-behav

Answer (score 2):

you can slice on `list2` based on the size you get from `list1`,

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val groupingList: List[Int] = List(5, 2, 4)
    val data = List("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k")

    //0, 5
    //5, (5 + 2)
    //5 + 2, (5 + 2 + 4)

    val grouped = groupingList.zipWithIndex.map { case (_, index) =>
      val start = groupingList.slice(0, index).sum
      val end = groupingList.slice(0, index + 1).sum

      data.slice(start, end)
    }

    println(grouped)
  }
```

**result:** `List(List(a, b, c, d, e), List(f, g), List(h, i, j, k))`

Also read: [How slice works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30235433/432903)

Answer (score 1):

i like show it using ex
list1=List("one","two","three")
List[String] = List(one, two, three)

list2=List("red","green","blue")
List[String] = List(red, green, blue)

list1::list2
List[java.io.Serializable] = List(List(one, two, three), red, green, blue)

var listSum=list1::list2
List[java.io.Serializable] = List(List(one, two, three), red, green, blue)

listSum
List[java.io.Serializable] = List(List(one, two, three), red, green, blue)

**we can "::" for insert one list to another list in Scala**

Answer (score 0):

Just found by me, even the following code worked, but the code posted by jwvh appears more concise than this, and I understand making list1 a Vector makes more sense regarding performance of element access in the following code:

```
list1.scan(0)(_+_).sliding(2).toList.map(x=>list2.drop(x(0)).take(x(1)-x(0)))
```

or

```
list1.scan(0)(_+_).zip(list1).map(x=>list2.drop(x._1).take(x._2))

list1.scan(0)(_+_).sliding(2).map(x=>list2.slice(x(0),x(1))).toList
```