# Why Scala 'String' object's iterator and 'List[Int]' object's iterator are behaving differently here?

Tags: string, scala, scala-collections

I just wanted to explore the behaviors of the iterators of a `String` object and a `List[Int]` object in REPL and the tests are as shown below:

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)

scala> val itL = list.iterator
itL: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> List(8,5,list.size-13).map(itL.take(_).mkString)
res85: List[String] = List(12345678, 910111213, 141516)

scala> val st = "abcdefghijklmnop"
st: String = abcdefghijklmnop

scala> val itS = st.iterator
itS: Iterator[Char] = non-empty iterator

scala> List(8,5,st.size-13).map(itS.take(_).mkString)
res84: List[String] = List(abcdefgh, abcde, abc)
```

Why the iterators are behaving differently? My expected output in `String` object's case is:

```
List[String] = List(abcdefgh, ijklm, nop)
```

Can somebody explain this if possible with examples.

**Another Observation is: The behaviour of the iterator of the `Range` object is also exactly similar to `String` object
as seen below:**

```
scala> val x = (1 to 16)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 16

scala> val t = (1 to 16).iterator
t: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> List(8,5,x.size-13).map(t.take(_).mkString)
res103: List[String] = List(12345678, 12345, 123)
```

**If the `Range` is converted to `List` or `Set` the respective iterators are behaving exactly as per my expectation always:**

```
scala> val x1 = (1 to 16).toList
x1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)

scala> val t1 = x1.iterator
t1: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> List(8,5,x1.size-13).map(t1.take(_).mkString)
res104: List[String] = List(12345678, 910111213, 141516)

scala> val x2 = (1 to 16).toSet
x2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 10, 14, 1, 6, 9, 13, 2, 12, 7, 3, 16, 11, 8, 4, 15)

scala> val t2 = x2.iterator
t2: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> List(8,5,x2.size-13).map(t2.take(_).mkString)
res105: List[String] = List(51014169132, 12731611, 8415)
```

Comment: In every example, `List`, `String`, `Range`, or `Set`, you're doing the same thing with the `Iterator`,  invoking the `take()` method multiple times. The documentation warns against that and says you'll get "undefined" results. It's no surprise you're seeing inconsistent output.

Comment: @GhostCat, Sorry, It should have been Unsalvageable → should be closed → unclear what you're asking. I will correct my option for such questions in future.

Comment: I appreciate the quick, kind and correct comeback ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a note attached to the `Iterator.take(n:Int)` [API documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html):

> Reuse: After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it was called on, and use only the iterator that was returned. Using the old iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in changes to the new iterator as well.

It looks like you've discovered some "undefined" behavior.

Comment: _*SIGH*_ So, anyone care to step into the light and explain their objections to my answer? The quoted documentation clearly states that what this code is doing (multiple `.take()` from the same `Iterator`) is in the realm of undefined. You might get useful output, you might not.

Comment: But I would refer to my question answered by you here using `take()` on iterator repeatedly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335281/splitting-a-scala-list-into-parts-using-a-given-list-of-part-sizes-partitioning..Reuse is not guaranteed as per the above API Documentation specification.